# MS Outlook- Preview is not being generated for embedded messages

Tags: email, outlook, office365, preview, mapi

We download emails from the Exchange and store their properties and content on a file system. The opposite operation is to create an empty message and copy all the properties of the original email to the new one (using a combination of C++ and MAPI).
Now, for particular journal emails from a client we produce strange behavior when after clicking on the attached message there is no preview generated by Outlook- although it has a a HTML body. A double-click is able to open the embedded message and it's body is also there. The version of Outlook doesn't matter as I've tried multiple versions.

I fear that there is a missing property which we failed to copy during our put together process back to the email which is needed by Outlook to generate the preview?

Can somebody tell me what logic Outlook is using to generate the Preview? What MAPI properties are being checked perhaps?

[image]

EDIT:
I've noticed that when I try to download the attached email using "Save As" then the downloaded email has no body at all. It's PR_HTML property is being removed completely

Comment: Have you tried to use tools such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy to compare properties set on the attached items when you do that manually and programmatically?

Comment: Sure, I use both of them regularly but still can't find the difference. Of course a lot of MAPI properties are different but still can't seem to find the cause for this behavior. Something must be with the body properties as PR_RTF_IN_SYNC is false in this case but if I hit forward on the email then Outlook is able to 'repair' the email with some magic and after that everything is correct with PR_RTF_IN_SYNC set back to true and the preview is being generated